# SQL: create a query with a column identifying each tuple of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been trying to find a solution for this SQL query:

```
|A|   |B|      |Output|
===========================
1      A          1
1      A          1
1      B          2
1      C          3
2      C          1
2      D          2
2      F          3
2      H          4
3      D          1
3      D          1
3      I          2
```

As you can see, I want to create a column (output) that identifies, not counts or sums, the occurrence of each (A,B) tuple, without removing repeated occurences.

How would you do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You might be interested of ranking functions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx

Comment: dont understand, in B column a has 2 occurance show output 1,H as 1 occurrence  showing 4, please provide proper formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up SQL Server Built-in [`DENSE_RANK()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) function.

```
SELECT * 
      ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [A] ORDER BY [B] ASC) AS [OutPut]
FROM TableName
```

Comment: Thanks so much, it's difficult to google or search thoroughly the documentation if you can't correctly frase what you're looking for. I would have never described what I was doing as "ranking" :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (partition by a order by b)
from table t;
```